# Flipping an array of points as a shape around its center vertically or horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, 2d

I have a web app that receives some array of points and I need to draw them on a canvas. Unfortunately, I get the dataset not the way I want. I need to rotate the shapes 180 degrees. Consider the diagram below:

[image: example]

Originally I get the points of the green rectangle. Example points:

(1,1), (3,1), (2, 3)

The order of points appearing in the dataset can varry...at the end it is the `path` that draws the shape.

Now I need to flip this vertically around its center to end up with the RED triangle. The coordinates will be:

(3,1), (3,3), (2,1)

Please see the example in the snippet. I have created this `flipVertical` function but it produces negative number. I think my formula my work for carthesian coordinates but not for 2D canvas which x,y are always positive.

I may get very complex shapes with many points...this triangle is only an example. what would be a good solution?

```js
    // Main template shape
    let shape = [{x: 10, y:10}, {x: 30, y:10}, {x: 20, y:30}];

    let canvas = {}; // Canvas to draw on
    let ctx = {}; // Context of the Canvas

    // Init elements
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        drawShape();
    });

    // Draw the template
    function drawShape() {
        
        
        // Original shape
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        for(let point of shape) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
        

         // Flipped shape
        ctx.save();
        let flippedShape = flipVertical(shape);
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        for(let point of flippedShape) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();

        
        
        
    }
    
    function flipVertical(points) {
      let ret = [];
      for(point of points) {
        let flipped = { x: point.x, y: -1 * point.y };
        console.log(flipped);
        ret.push(flipped);
      }
      
      return ret;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>HELP ME!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: y: 40 - point.y ?  In your example, y values of 10, 10, 30 become 30, 30, 10.  40 would be twice the y value of the midway point - in this case, (30-10)*2

Comment: @ATD Well thats a good hint...but how can I calculate that mid point for more complex shapes with many more points?

Comment: You will need to loop through the shape array and find the highest and lowest values for the y value.  I assume that the flip needs to be around the mid-point between these two, so a simple (max-min)*2 gives you the mid-point.

Answer (score 1):

To find the mid-point, do something like:

```js
let shape = [{x: 10, y:10}, {x: 30, y:10}, {x: 20, y:30}];

function getMinMax({min, max}, shape) {
    if (shape.y < min) {min = shape.y;}
    if (shape.y > max) {max = shape.y;}
    return {min, max}
}

var initValues = {min: Infinity, max: -Infinity};
var {min, max} = shape.reduce(getMinMax, initValues);
console.log("min y: " + min + ", max y: " + max);
```

This gives you the min/max values in y.  Then:

```
let x = (max-min)*2;
let flipped = { x: point.x, y: x - point.y };
```

which should then change 10, 10, 30 into 30, 30, 10

Comment: let x = max + min;  would give the same result as well

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your picture is more than flipping the coordinates. It's flipping them and then arbitrarily repositioning them.

Here's flipping the points:

```js
// Main template shape
    let shape = [{x: 10, y:10}, {x: 30, y:10}, {x: 20, y:30}];

    let canvas = {}; // Canvas to draw on
    let ctx = {}; // Context of the Canvas

    // Init elements
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        drawShape();
    });

    // Draw the template
    function drawShape() {
        
        
        // Original shape
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        for(let point of shape) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
        

         // Flipped shape
        ctx.save();
        let flippedShape = flipVertical(shape);
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        for(let point of flippedShape) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();

        
        
        
    }
    
    function flipVertical(points) {
      let ret = [];
      var min_x, min_y;
      for(point of points) {
        let flipped = { x: canvas.width - point.x, y: canvas.width - point.y };
        ret.push(flipped);
      }
      
      return ret;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hmm the red trinagle ends up in the lower right corner of the canvase :(

Comment: correct. that's what happens if you take a picture of a triangle in the top corner of an image and flip it. that's flipping the coordinates, like you asked.

Comment: I mean I want the triangle itself be flipped around its own center :)